# How do I submit a post to the Ask HN section of the Hacker News website?

Tags: hacker-news

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but I can't figure out how to submit a question to the [Ask HN](http://news.ycombinator.com/ask) section of the Hacker News website. How do I do this?

Answer (score 20):

1. Click the [submit](http://news.ycombinator.com/submit) link at the
   top of the page.
2. Log in, if necessary.
3. Fill out the form.

**Note to start an "Ask HN:" discussion, you must fill out the form in a special way:**

1. Start *title* with "Ask HN:"
2. Enter your question as the rest of the *title* field.
3. Leave the *URL* field blank.
4. Optionally put a more detailed explanation of your question in the *text* field. This will appear at the top if someone views your submission.

Answer (score 6):

There's a Submit link in the header - or just head over to this link directly -->  http://news.ycombinator.com/submit with "Ask HN:" prefixed to the title

[image]

Comment: Image is missing, with an error message.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo thanks for letting me know, fixed

Answer (score 1):

It's worth pointing out that Hacker News doesn't have any "sections" per se. It's just something that people put at the front of the subject.

Comment: I think the question author is referring to this page/section: https://news.ycombinator.com/ask

Comment: @GabeKopley, That page shows all posts without urls. You don't need prefix `Ask HN:`/`Tell HN:`.